# How to get the output of container_commands after deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

My Elastic Beanstalk container uses [container_commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) to run a script to patch the database on every deployment.

I run the deployments with a home-brewed script that calls the [UpdateEnvironment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateEnvironment.html) on the Elastic Beanstalk API.

The problem is, I have no visibility on the output of my `container_commands`, which is pretty scary during deployment. The only way I can tell if something went wrong is when a command returns a non-zero value: in that case [DescribeEvents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeEvents.html) will report a problem. But still, I have no way to get the actual output of the command.

**How can I get my `container_commands` output after the deployment has finished?**

Ideally, with the Elastic Beanstalk API, but any other programmatic way will be fine!

Comment: You may look into this following link.
http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reply from the [AWS support](http://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/):

> The easiest way to see the output would be to pipe the command or script output to a file using `>>`. Unfortunately there isn't a live console that can be viewed to show the process live.

So unfortunately there is no way to do that (yet).

Answer (score 17):

Not a console view, but it is (now) visible in the logs.

**.ebextensions/10-log.config**

```
container_commands:
  05-whoami:
    command: "whoami"
```

**/var/log/cfn-init.log** after deployment

```
2014-07-01 22:08:10,695 [DEBUG] Running command 05-whoami
2014-07-01 22:08:10,695 [DEBUG] Generating defaults for command 05-whoami
2014-07-01 22:08:11,014 [DEBUG] Defaults script for 05-whoami output: {"env":{"EB_REQUEST_ID":"110d0932-016c-11e4-9f71-3fe967c5cd60", [long list of params omitted for brevity]}
2014-07-01 22:08:11,015 [DEBUG] No test for command 05-whoami
2014-07-01 22:08:11,050 [INFO] Command 05-whoami succeeded
2014-07-01 22:08:11,050 [DEBUG] Command 05-whoami output: root
```

Comment: found mine in `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log`

Answer (score 0):

Like @otaku mentioned above in one of the comments, I also located my command output in `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log`.

Here's what I was trying to run:

```
container_commands:
  20-migrate_database:
    command: |
      bash ./bin/export_database_migrations_url.sh
      bash ./bin/run_migrations.sh
    leader_only: true
```

The originally accepted answers are now a bit dated (as of May 2023). I'm sure they were right at the time, but this might be where to look if you're reading this nowadays.